# Can I make an element inherit the properties of other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We're providing a pre-populated WordPress site for multiple members to use on their servers. The theme has a selector where they can customize their heading colours and fonts. Each member will have different colours based on their branding.

The site also includes a knowledgebase plugin and it uses its own colours which can be customized within its interface. Instead, we'd like to be able to set the knowedgebase colours/properties based on the theme's colour palette. (Ultimately, we'd like the member to only have to change the colors for the theme in one place rather than customize every single plugin.)

So, if H1 is globally set to blue, we'd like to be able to tell the knowledgebase's element (.kb-header) to be the same colour as H1.

Is this at all doable via CSS or Javascript or something?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make an element to inherit the properties of a parent element. For example:

```css
p { color: red; }
a { color: inherit; }
```

```html
<p>Paragraph with <a href="#">link</a></p>
```

But definitely this won't work for what you're asking if your `.kb-header` is not a child of your `h1`.

Instead you could use different approaches to get the desired result. For example with [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (a.k.a CSS variables)

```css
:root {
  --user-color: red;
}

h1 {
  color: var(--user-color);
}

.kb-header {
  color: var(--user-color);
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<header class="kb-header">This is the header</header>
```

This way you could, for example, output your `:root` selector defining all your custom properties in your `<head>` tag using PHP. And your CSS would be totally independent from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inherit (Object Oriented Programing like) if the html tags doesn't have any relationship, you can use SCSS, for example SASS, it's a text pre processor that generates the CSS with a CSS-like coding with the addition that you can use variables and much more.

For more details [visit SASS lang webpage](https://sass-lang.com/) i think this can help you a lot for mostly all your projects.

If you don't want to use SASS, you can even use javascript (with or without libraries) to reach this job, as plain CSS is not capable to conditionally apply styles between non-related tags.

Comment: This won't work with SASS variables because in production you'll have your variables transpiled as constant values. So, you won't be able to update the variables for every user.

Comment: it can work if you generate different userID-based classes on target elements on server-side before printing the client-side, as you're doing mostly the same with content on wordpress. If you don't want to deal with this clean option, you can override properties with javascipt which is less recommended due to load speed and load.

Comment: Remember that you can compile SASS dynamically during runtime, and, of course, add a different css style sheet for every user and load dynamically the one you need depending on the user. Which is a good option to deal with this logic

Comment: I wouldn't recommend compiling SASS at runtime, but yes, that could do the trick.

Comment: you only have to compile it whenever a user changes some color value and save it, so it's not an on-load job.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a miniature version of what you're looking for. Hope this helps :P

```
<html>
<style>
h1 {
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
<body>
<h1>Hey!</h1>
<div class="kb-header">I'm a div :)</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bgColor = $("h1").css("background-color");
    $(".kb-header").css({"background-color": bgColor});
});
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can combine selectors with a comma and have a single block of rules for both:
 `.a, .b { property: value; }`.
And still style one or another selector with other declarations (example below).

When selectors are unrelated, it causes maintenance problems but if it's generated by a theme generator, that should be OK (you don't want to style those given components but have a clear documented list of what has to be styled with a set of colors).

```css
h1,
.kb-header {
  color: darkred;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
@media (min-width: 961px) {
  .kb-header {
    border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Unstyled paragraph</p>
<header class="kb-header">This is the header</header>
```

You can also add a utility class to all elements that are to be styled with a border, a background color and a color:

```css
/* Theme 1
 Primary color: #0055D0
 Secondary color: #080;
*/

.c-primary {
  color: #0055D0;
}

.bd-secondary {
  border: 1px solid #080;
}

/* Common styles */
h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.kb-header {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="c-primary">Title</h1>

<header class="kb-header bd-secondary c-primary">This is the header</header>
```

Other answers talking about a Sass environment (or other preprocessors like PostCSS and LESS) and CSS "Variables" (if you don't have to support old browsers like IE11 and Edge ~15 + Saf (iOS and OS X) 9.2 https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20prop are also fine solutions to your problem IMHO.